# Why do atoms only absorb energy in the form of radiation or heat?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation

Why do atoms eject electrons only if they are provided energy in the form of radiation(photons) or heat(thermal energy or friction)?

Why can't we excite atoms by increasing its other energies like kinetic energy?

for example if I increase the velocity of an atom and atom gains kinetic energy. What will happen to its electrons? will the atom eject electrons? Can we ionize an atom just by increasing its speed?

or If I accelerate the atom, will it make the atom eject electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have to distinguish the motion/energy of the center of mass of the atom, and the relative motion of the nucleus and the electrons. Accelerating the atom as a whole, i.e. changing the kinetic energy of its center of mass, does nothing to the relative motion of the constituing particles. Radiation is, on the other hand, an easiest way to interact with the inner degrees of freedom.

Yet, strictly speaking, radiation is not the exclusive way to change the state if an atom. If an accelerated atom hits something or passes through a region with strong electric field, its kinetic energy may be transferred to its internal motion. An easy example is the neon lights, where atoms are excited via collisions with energetic electrons and then release the acquired energy as light.

Comment: Thank you so much, But I have one more doubt, when radiation strikes an atom, does it directly strike just the electron ? the probability of striking just the electron is near impossible isn't it? Then what does the photon strike to excite the atom?

Comment: Radiation is an electric field that varies in time, whereas the pisitively charged nucleus and the ekectron form a dipole, interacting with this field.

Answer (score 0):

Up to this last sentence :

> or If I accelerate the atom, will it make the atom eject electron?

Your questions is adequately answered within classical physics.

Electrons and the structure of the atoms belong to the realm of quantum mechanics. For an electron to be ejected from its orbital about the atom  a definite energy must be provided in the form of a photon, the atom will absorb the photon and eject the electron if the energy is exact, or the photon can scatter off the total atom and both  an electron and a reduced in energy photon go away. Just accelerating an atom will not extract an electron.

Answer (score -1):

"Kinetic energy", "radiations", these are mere names. Kinetic energy is seen to work with the external changes, while running, while the molecules vibrate. So, in my opinion, it is not feasible to use kinetic energy.

But thinking on the terms of definition, kinetic energy is the energy possessed by a body in motion. So while an electron ejects out of an atom, it possesses kinetic energy, as it is in motion. But kinetic energy was defined on the basis of the motion of whole bodies bigger than object rather than the things that make up the atom. So we should wait for the researches. The energy dealing with bodies may not deal with the constituent particles.

Comment: Thanks I understood